# Hotkey to copy selected text from Spyder console, including "In []: " prompts

Tags: spyder

When copying selected text from the Spyder console, the `In []:`  prompts get selected, but they aren't present in the text when copy and pasted into a text editor using `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`.  Is there any way to copy and paste *all* selected text, including the prompts?

Note that there is a menu item `Edit -> Copy (Ctrl+C)` which *does*
include the `In []:`  prompts.  Despite the fact that it claims
`Ctrl+C` as a shortcut key, however, it obviously doesn't invoke the
same functionality because `Ctrl+C` does not include the `In []:` 
prompts.  I very much prefer hotkeys over mousing to different
menu items, so it'd be great if I could have a hotkey copy the selected
text, incluiding `In []:`  prompts.

I am using Spyder as part of Anaconda on Windows.